# How to customize the CKEditor's Styles menu in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, ckeditor

In a Joomla website, I have enabled the CKEditor as default text editor. I want to define some custom styles, that will be displayed in the Styles menu. I have found [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles) of the CKEditor that describes how this should work, but I cannot figure out how to implement this in my Joomla site.

As per the documentation, I have tried to edit the 'default' styleset by adding my own definitions, but this has no effect.

I have also tried to create a new styleset and add this to the editor, but this has also no effect. I can find only one or two places where `CKEDITOR.addStylesSet` or `config.stylesCombo_stylesSet = 'default'` appears in the code, but editing these files has no effect, as if some other code overrules the config in these files.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the joomla component (If working with Joomla 1.6). I've had the same error, debugged it to find out that they use a different folder than stated at the tooltip.

They say:
"This file should exist in the plugins/editors/ckeditor/styles folder"

What actually happens is the PHP code checking for file existance at:

```
plugins/editors/ckeditor/ckeditor/styles
```

and then uses their stated folder to load the actual file

It appears that this is the code that causes the error:

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'ckeditor'.DS.'styles'.DS.$style_file))
```

note the extra 'ckeditor'

Anyway, this folder doesn't exist. You should create it, and put a file in it to bypass the existence check.

Same thing with the "Templates" file...